# /etc/passwd update not working

Tags: linux, etc, passwd

In one of the machines I work with I'm seeing a strange behaviour. I've manually changed the shell of one user in /etc/passwd but when I try to login with that user, it still uses the old one. getent also shows the old one. But a grep on the /etc/passwd file confirms I saved the file correctly.

Is there (on Linux) any kind of /etc/passwd caching?

How to avoid it?

Comment: Whats the output of `grep <that_user> /etc/passwd`?

Comment: The output of a grep is a correct line with the new shell I put by hand

Comment: you should have used `chsh <username>`...

Comment: Consider posting the output here, and mask if there are any private stuffs present.

Comment: This information _could_ be stored in your company LDAP/AD, in particular, if the machine is set up to authenticate against LDAP/AD anyway.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Right, or on a NIS/YP remote server. 
Envite, what is the content of the "passwd:" line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: It is not stored on LDAP, AD, NIS or YP. Even if the computer were configured to use those, I'm talking about a user configured locally in `/etc/passwd`. In fact, the computer is configured that way: `nsswitch.conf` uses `passwd: compat` and there are no other sources where this user could exist. What I'm asking about is truly caching of `/etc/passwd` since after waiting some minutes, all symptoms disappear, and this is reproducible with each change made on `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Another possibility is that you have two entries with he same UID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a process named `nscd` running? That's the name service caching daemon.

If it is running, you may need to run `sudo nscd -i passwd` to tell it that it should forget any cached `/etc/passwd` file data. It has other caches too: the respective keywords for them are `group`, `hosts`, `services` and `netgroup`.

It is more commonly used with LDAP/AD/NIS-based authentication schemes, but may improve system performance if you're running some process that makes a very large number of user/group/service/hosts-file look-ups. Or if you have installed some services you're not actually using (perhaps to use just a small part of them), some service may have pulled `nscd` in as a dependency.